# Could a "Modified" Density of subsets of $[a,b]$, using a "modified" Folner Net, give the same results as the Lebesgue measure of these subsets?

Tags: lebesgue-measure, amenability

I read a [research paper](http://nhindman.us/research/density.pdf) stating we can extend the definition of a Density,  that uses a Folner Sequence of countable sets, to one that uses Folner Nets of Uncountable sets (ex: $\mathbb{R}$). I couldn’t decipher the definitions so I'm unsure how to apply this Density to any subset of $\mathbb{R}$ or check a "modified version" of this density equals the Lebesgue measure of these sets.

Let $S$ be a semigroup and let $\mathcal{F}=\langle F_{n} \rangle_{n\in D}$ be a net in $\mathcal{P}_{f}(S)$, where $\mathcal{P}_{f}(S)$ is the set of all non-empty finite subsets of $S$. Then $\mathcal{F}$ is the left Folner Net if and only if for each $s\in S$, the net

$$\left\langle \frac{\left|sF_{n}\triangle F_n\right|}{\left|F_n\right|} \right\rangle_{n\in D}$$

converges to zero. Also $\mathcal{F}$ is a right Folner Net if and only if for each $s\in S$, the net

$$\left\langle \frac{\left|F_{n}s\triangle F_n\right|}{\left|F_n\right|} \right\rangle_{n\in D}$$

converges to zero.

The "modified" Folner Net is simply $\mathcal{F}_{[a,b]}=\langle F_n \cap [a,b] \rangle_{n\in D}$ for $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$

If this is the case, the "modified" density, ${{d}^{*}}_{\mathcal{F}_{[a,b]}}(A\cap[a,b])$, using nets in $\mathcal{P}_{f}(s)$, for $a\le s \le b$ and $A\cap[a,b]\subseteq{S}\cap[a,b]$, is

$$\underline{d}_{\mathcal{F}_{[a,b]}}(A\cap[a,b])\le {{d}^{*}}_{\mathcal{F}_{[a,b]}}(A\cap[a,b]) \le \overline{d}_{\mathcal{F}_{[a,b]}}(A\cap[a,b])$$

(a) The lower density is $$\underline{d}_{\mathcal{F}_{[a,b]}}(A\cap[a,b])=\sup\left\{\alpha:(\exists m \in D)(\forall n \ge m)(\left|A\cap F_n\cap[a,b]\right|)\ge \alpha*\left|F_n\cap[a,b]\right|\right\}$$

(b) The upper density is $$\overline{d}_{\mathcal{F}_{[a,b]}}(A\cap[a,b])=\sup\left\{\alpha:(\forall m \in D)(\exists n \ge m)(\left|A\cap F_n\cap[a,b]\right|)\ge \alpha*\left|F_n\cap[a,b]\right|\right\}$$

(c) And the Density squeezed between is $${{d}^{*}}_{\mathcal{F}_{[a,b]}}(A\cap[a,b])=\sup\left\{\alpha:(\forall m \in D)(\exists n \ge m)(\exists x \in S \cup {1})(\left|A\cap F_n x \cap [a,b]\right|)\ge \alpha*\left|F_n\cap[a,b]\right|\right\}$$

If $A\cap[a,b]=\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}\cap[a,b]$ and $S=[a,b]$ what is ${{d}^{*}}_{\mathcal{F}_{[a,b]}}(A\cap[a,b])$? What if $A=\mathbb{Q}\cap[a,b]$ and $S=[a,b]$? If there is no single value for these densities can we find a Folner Net of $S\cap[a,b]$ where ${{d}^{*}}_{\mathcal{F}_{[a,b]}}(A\cap[a,b])$ give similar results to $\mu(A\cap[a,b])$, where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue Measure?

Edit: If $S\cap[a,b]=[a,b]$ the paper states that ${d^{*}}_{\mathcal{F}_{[a,b]}}(A)\ge\mu(A\cap[a,b])$ where $\mu$ is a countable additive measure. If the measure was Lebesgue, could we take a specific $F_n$ so that ${d^{*}}_{\mathcal{F}_{[a,b]}}(A\cap[a,b])=\mu(A\cap[a,b])$?

Comment: The density $d^*_{\mathcal F}$ is not similar to Lebesgue measure $\mu$, because $ d^*_{\mathcal F}(A)\le 1$ for each $A\subset\Bbb R$, whereas $\mu(A)$ can be arbitrarily big. Maybe also for each Lebesgue measurable subset $A$ of $\Bbb R$ with finite $\mu(A)$ we have $d^*_{\mathcal F}(A)=0$ for each left Følner net $\mathcal F$ on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky What if we restricted the Density to using the Folner Net of interval $S=[a,b]$? For $d^{*}_{\mathcal{F}}(A)$ where $A\subset[a,b]$, could we find a Folner Net of $S$ such that $d^{*}_{\mathcal{F}}(A)=\mu(A)$?

Comment: If $a<b$ then $[a,b]$ is not a semigroup with respect to addition, so for $F_n\subset [a,b]$, and $s\in [a,b]$, $s+F_n$ not always contained in $[a,b]$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Could we redefine Folner Sequences/Nets so it can be used for elements only in $[a,b]$. For example, I want a “redefined Folner Sequence” of $\mathbb{Q}\cap[a,b]$, instead of $\mathbb{Q}$, such that $F_{n,a,b}=\left\{\frac{j}{k}:1\le k \le n, a\le\left|\frac{j}{k}\right|\le b\right\}$ instead of $F_{n}=\left\{\frac{j}{k}:1\le k \le n, \left|\frac{j}{k}\right|\le n\right\}$, where $j,a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$, $k,r\in\mathbb{N}$ and $a<b$. How can we redefine Folner Nets to apply to uncountable sets, such as $\mathbb{R}$, in $[a,b]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment.

A density of a set can be defined by means of any net in $\mathcal P_f(S)$ (see Definition 2.1 of the paper). But I guess that from the amenability point of view a purpose of Følner nets is to define a left-shift invariant measure on the family of subsets of $S$, see, for instance, paragraph after Definition 1.6, Theorems 4.5 and 4.17. For this purpose translations are in the definitions of Følner sequences or nets.

On the other hand, if we a looking for translation invariance then it seems the following (I didn’t perfectly check this paragraph). From the measure point of view we can identify an interval $[0,1)$ with the unit circle $\Bbb T=\{ z\in\Bbb C: |z|=1\}$ which is a group by a map $f:[0,1)\to\Bbb T$, $t\mapsto e^{2\pi it}$. Since $\Bbb T$ is a compact topological group,  in admits a Haar measure $\lambda$. Then for any Borel subset $A$ of $[0,1)$ the set $f(A)$ is Borel in $\Bbb T$, so the value $\lambda(f(A))$ is defined and equals to Lebesgue measure of the set $A$.

Recall that by a Haar measure on a locally compact group we understand any left-invariant Borel regular $\sigma$-additive measure that takes positive ﬁnite values on compact sets with non-empty interior. It is well-known that each locally compact topological group has a Haar measure and such measure is unique up to a positive multiplicative constant. On the other hand, the Haar measure does not exists in non-locally compact groups.

At last, I remember that recently my boss Taras Banakh considered relations between measures and densities on groups, so maybe in the following papers you can find something useful for you:

- T.Banakh, *[Extremal densities and measures on groups and $G$-spaces and their combinatorial applications](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.5078)*.
- T.Banakh, *[The Solecki submeasures and densities on groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.0717)*.
- T.Banakh, I.Protasov, S.Slobodianiuk, *[Densities, submeasures and partitions of groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.4612)*, Algebra Discr. Math., **17**:2 (2014), 193-221.

Comment: I modified the old definition of density on my post. Does this change the answers to my questions?